# How come my player lives is not reseting on every screen load?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Summary**
My player lives is not reseting to the default value when they start the game over or enter the next level. When I die once and then complete the first level. The 2nd lvl loads and I start out with 2 lives. When I die 3xs it loads the main menu and when I click on start button it starts me off with 1 life.

**LayOut:**
[Unity Hierarchy LayOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzVjj.png)

*Goal:*

To have the player lives reset to 3 when re/starting the game/next Level.

*Expected Results:*

When the player completes a level with 2 lives left. The next level should load displaying that the player has 3 lives.

*Actual Results:*

When the player completes a level with 2 lives left. The next level displays that the player has 2 lives instead of 3.

**Error Messages:**
NONE

**What I Tried**
I am lost this is my first time creating a game. Where a player has multiple lives.

**SpaceShip CODE:**

```
public void completeSequence()
    {
        player = playerState.Transcending;
        SFX.Stop();
        SFX.PlayOneShot(completed);
        death.Stop();
        victory.Play();
        Invoke("loadNextLevel", lvlLoadDelay);
    }

    public void resetLvl()
    {
        //print("Dead");
        player = playerState.Dying;
        SFX.Stop();
        SFX.PlayOneShot(dead);
        death.Play();
        Invoke("loadCurrentSccene", lvlLoadDelay);

    }

    public void deadSequence()
    {
        //print("Dead");
        player = playerState.Dying;
        SFX.Stop();
        SFX.PlayOneShot(dead);
        death.Play();
        Invoke("loadMainLevel", lvlLoadDelay);
    }

    public void loadCurrentSccene()
    {
        var currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene);
    }

    public void loadMainLevel() 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

    public void loadNextLevel()
    {
        int currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        //print(currentScene);
        int nextScene = currentScene +1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);
    }

    public void loadPreviousLevel()
    {
        int currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        int nextScene = currentScene -1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);
    }
}
```

**GameSession Code:**

```
{
    [SerializeField] int playerLives = 3;
    [SerializeField] Text livesText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        int numSessions = FindObjectsOfType<gameSession>().Length;

        if (numSessions > 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("I am the NOT Original");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("I am the Original");
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }

    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        livesText.text = playerLives.ToString();
    }

    public void initiateDeath()
    {
        if (playerLives > 1)
        {
            reduceLives();
        }
        else
            {
            FindObjectOfType<spaceShip>().deadSequence();
        }
    }

    public void reduceLives()
    {
        playerLives--;
        FindObjectOfType<spaceShip>().resetLvl();
        livesText.text = playerLives.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: The Visual Studio tag was not appropriate since the question is not about Visual Studio itself so I removed it.  When choosing tags, be sure to read their descriptions to make sure they are appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `playerLives` is being initialized to `3`, and reduced by one whenever `reduceLives()` is called. None of your code sets `playerLives` back to `3`, so when you enter a new level or call `deadSequence()` the lives stay at their previous value.

Adding a reset method to **GameSession** and calling this whenever you want to set the `playerLives` back to `3` (so presumably inside of both `deadSequence()` and `completeSequence()`) will fix this issue.

```
public void ResetLives()
{
    playerLives = 3;
    livesText.text = playerLives.ToString();
}
```